# Talend - delete folder

Tags: talend

I have a talend job that create folder based on account ID on a specific folder(C/LogDetails).

Job run every 5 mins and because of this I have no space left in the directory and this prevent job from creating more folders based on account ID.

In short because of lack of space in the folder(C/LogDetails) the job failed.

I want to build a solution in talend that will delete all folders where date modified must be less than today's date.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which OS is this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
in tFileList give the parent folder path c/LogDetails and select 'directories' in FileList type dropdown.

in tFileProperties component use the global variable ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")). it will iterate all the folders inside your parent folder because you have selected fileList type as directories in tFileList component.

in tJavaRow use below code 
if(TalendDate.compareDate(TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd")),
TalendDate.parseDate("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", row1.mtime_string)) == 1) {

context.abs_path = input_row.abs_path;
System.out.println("if : "+context.abs_path);

}

join tjavarow with if condition to tFileDelete component. If conditon should be context.abs_path should not be null or empty. give the context.abs_path in tFileDelete and select delete folder option

hope this help..:)